# How to read unstructured csv file like this to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

When I do:

```
data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv',sep = ',',header = None)
```

I got:

```
0   age=Middle-aged,education=Bachelors,native-cou...
1   age=Middle-aged,education=Bachelors,native-cou...
```

The row number is correct, but how do I extracted the variable names(headers) such as age, education, native-country and use the value after '=' as the value for each header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` those long strings on the commas and stack it all into one big Series. Then extract the fields around the `'='` to get the column name and the value. Pivot this to reshape back to one row per original index.

```
(df[0].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
      .str.extractall(r'(?P<col>.*)=(?P<val>.*)')
      .reset_index([-1,-2], drop=True)
      .pivot(columns='col', values='val')
      .rename_axis(columns=None))
```

---

```
           age  education native-country   race
0  Middle-aged  Bachelors  United-States  White
1  Middle-aged  Bachelors  United-States  White
```

#### Sample Data

```
d = {0: {0: 'age=Middle-aged,education=Bachelors,native-country=United-States,race=White', 
         1: 'age=Middle-aged,education=Bachelors,native-country=United-States,race=White'}}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I have a question, for the code 'str.extractall(r'(?P<col>.*)=(?P<val>.*)')', what are the coding doing between the '=' sign?

Comment: I'm only *okay* at regex, but there's probably a pattern for `.str.extractall` that can be used to get everything without the first split. The lack of a comma after the final field is tripping me up.

Comment: no need to use regex, pandas applymap function should be enough. more information is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Comment: @YuanShi Those are  named capturing groups. So the first captures everything up to the equals sign (and puts it in a column named 'col') The second does the same for everything after the equals sign. Run the first line of code alone and then run the first and second lines together and you should be able to see what they do.

Comment: @ ALollz, that's clear, thanks! BTW, if the two rows are written in one row, and we know the size for each row should be 4, is there a way I can let pandas read 4 object, then jump to the second row?

Answer (score 0):

how about splitting with = and then taking the last element of list using pandas `applymap` function ?

for example: this should do it.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('=')[-1])

           age  education
0  Middle-aged  Bachelors
1  Middle-aged  Bachelors
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I only got one row
0
0 White
1 White

Comment: It works in my case, not sure why doesn't it work on your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  If you know the column names, the simplest is way is to use the `converters` argument to `read_csv()`.  Pass in a dict mapping column names or number to a function.  Here the function splits the string on the `=` and returns the part on the right.

```
converters = {n:lambda s:s.split('=')[1] for n in range(3)}

pd.read_csv(f, converters=converters, header=None, names='age education native-country'.split())
```

Returns:

```
    age         education   native-country
0   Middle-aged Bachelors   United States
1   Middle-aged Bachelors   United States
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way to make progress on this is to make sure that the input file is a valid CSV-formatted file (if it possible to change the format of your `temp.csv` file).

In a CSV file, the values in each cell are not prefixed with the column name so, the lines in the file should look like this `Middle-aged,Bachelors,United-States,White` rather than this `age=Middle-aged,education=Bachelors,native-country=United-States,race=White`.